# Create static array using Class.forName

Tags: java, android, static-array

In Android there is a undeclared (hidden) class named "android.graphics.FontFamily" and I want to create static array of it. Any thing like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.graphics.FontFamily"); // Ok.
Class<?> clazz_array = Class.forName("android.graphics.FontFamily[]"); // Method threw 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' exception.
```

To build this hypothetical code:

```
FontFamily[] families = {fontFamily};
```

How can I do it?

Thankyou.

Comment: What does "undeclared (hidden) class" means? It means `private`, `nested static private` or `inner private`?

Comment: see `Array.newInstance`, documentation

Comment: @pskink If I understood well the array isn't declared in that class, he simply wants to create an array of that private class

Comment: @Fondesa, yes, `he simply wants to create an array of that hidden class `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create an array reflectively then get its class. Example:

```
Class <?> clazz = Class.forName("android.graphics.FontFamily");
Object fontFamily = clazz.newInstance();
Object families = Array.newInstance(clazz, 1);
Array.set(families, 0, fontFamily);
```

Comment: Ok, clazzArray is class, and how can I instantiante an instance of it which has 1 item (like FontFamily[] families = {fontFamily})?

Comment: @mhtaqia see `java.lang.reflect.Array` documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the fully-qualified name as specified in the [`Class` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html). So in your case it would be:

```
Class<?> clazzArray = Class.forName("[Landroid.graphics.FontFamily;");
```

The `[` indicates an array, and then the `L` prefix and semi-colon suffix are to indicate that the part in the middle is a class name.